# JMS Correlation ID is different in MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm writing a java spring boot app that connects to MQ, read messages (placed by another app) and returns a response to them.

I'm trying to set the correlation id to the message ID we've just received.

```
public void sendMessage(String destination, Item item, Message originalMessage) throws IOException {
    jmsTemplate.send(destinationName, session -> {

        Message message = createBytesMessage(item, session);

        message.setJMSCorrelationID(originalMessage.getJMSMessageID());

        log.info("Message: " + message);

        return message;
    });
}
```

The original message ID is:

```
ID:414d5120514d44454c30315020202020f8af4d6202558722
```

The reply message has a correlation ID as expected:

```
ID:414d5120514d44454c30315020202020f8af4d6202558722
```

However, when I investigate MQ I can see the correlation ID is actually:

```
343134643531323035313464343434353463333033313530
```

Curiously, if I take my expected value for the correlation and covert that to a hexdecimal, I get the following:

```
343134643531323035313464343434353463333033313530323032303230323066386166346436323032383338343232
// The first 48 characters match what is in MQ
```

Here is the debug information from the java application:

This is the original message:

```
JMSMessage class: jms_bytes
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  1
  JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
  JMSDeliveryTime:  0
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      0
  JMSMessageID:     ID:414d5120514d44454c30315020202020f8af4d6202558722
  JMSTimestamp:     1649452421210
  JMSCorrelationID: null
  JMSDestination:   null
  JMSRedelivered:   false
    JMSXAppID: DataFlowEngine              
    JMSXDeliveryCount: 1
    JMSXUserID: mqm         
    JMS_IBM_Character_Set: UTF-8
    JMS_IBM_Encoding: 546
    JMS_IBM_Format:         
    JMS_IBM_MsgType: 1
    JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 6
    JMS_IBM_PutDate: 20220408
    JMS_IBM_PutTime: 21134121
```

This is the debug for the out bound message:

```
2022-04-08 22:13:42.020 DEBUG 31180 --- [enerContainer-1] o.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate   : Sending created message: 
  JMSMessage class: jms_bytes
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSDeliveryDelay: 0
  JMSDeliveryTime:  0
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      4
  JMSMessageID:     null
  JMSTimestamp:     0
  JMSCorrelationID: ID:414d5120514d44454c30315020202020f8af4d6202558722
  JMSDestination:   null
  JMSReplyTo:       null
  JMSRedelivered:   false
7b22747261636b696e674964223a312c22737461747573223a2244454c495645524544222c226465
6c697665727944617465223a22323032322d30312d3031222c2274797065223a225345434f4e445f
434c415353227d
```

Comment: You say CorrelationID is as expected. So what is the problem you are facing? You mention "investigated MQ", what and how did you investigated?

Comment: I used the MQExplorer tool which reports the CorrelationID is the third one I posted (343...)

Comment: When you browse a message and display it's contents, MQExplorer displayes identifiers, MessageID and CorrelationID in hex. So I am wondering how CorrelationID is displayed in decimal. Can you update you question with screeshot of the problem?

Comment: The Explorer tool was set to "Hex" at the time when I pulled the value out. 

I've changed nothing (I believe) but am unable to repeat the problem this morning - the correlation ID's now match as expected...